# Fast way to get all users + specify attribute + use paging from LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I would like to get all users with their attributes from active directory
I checked many topics includes Linq to LDAP + [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#26)

But all seems to be complicated.

I started with this:

```
public SearchResultCollection GetAllUsrs()
     {
         var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", "x.y.com", "DC=x,DC=y,DC=com"));
         var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
         searcher.Filter = "(&(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)))";
         searcher.PageSize = 999;

         return searcher.FindAll();

     }
```

How can i use pagging since the active directory will only return 1000 record at the time
+ how can i specify the attribute?

Problem:
I want to query a domain that contain up to 60 K users with console application
I want to specify the attribute 
Performance is very important. 
Can you please guide me to the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Paging is not required. AD will return more than 1000 objects.  Leave PageSize at 0 and set SizeLimit as required.  Use int.MaxValue ;) if you're unsure.

Comment: If i try to return more than 1000 record at the time, my account get blocked. i think it's a company policy.

Comment: You mean it gets locked out? "net user %username% /domain" shows: Account active No? I've never heard of a query locking out an account if the supplied password is correct...

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it with [LINQ to LDAP](http://linqtoldap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Paging&referringTitle=Querying):

```
using (var connection = new LdapConnection("x.y.com"))
{
     using (var context = new DirectoryContext(connection))
     {
          List<IDirectoryAttributes> users = context
               .Query("DC=x,DC=y,DC=com")
               .Where("(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person))")
               .InPagesOf(1000);
     }
}
```